# Key as ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code.

```
<select id="block-rule"
   class="form-control"
   name="rule"
   ng-model="forms.block.fields.rule">
      <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in rules" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

I'm not really familiar with AngularJS, but I can see, that it should iterate "rules" (as specified in `ng-repeat`), and it works right.

Thing that don't work - default value is not selected. As I can see, value that should be selected initially is need to be passed to `ng-model`.

`forms.block.fields.rule`, I think, contains a `value`, but I need to get a `key`.

Unfortunately, it's the only part of code I can show.

Comment: Using the Batarang extension should help you see the values of the app. It is in the Chrome Web Store. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in rules" ng-model="forms.block.fields.rule">
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/559nX/)**

Comment: I've kept forms.block.fields.rule as ng-model and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-options but it may require you to change your rule model slightly (add a name property):

```
<select id="block-rule"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="rule"
                        ng-    model="forms.block.fields.rule"
                        ng-options="rule as rule.name for rule in rules"
                >
 </select>
```